# Using raster calculator in the graphical modeler of QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

[image]I have a raster with slope values and want to calculate a raster, which only shows values under and over a certain threshold for example 50. In the raster calculator I can do this manually by the expression

"Slope@1"  >= 50

As I want to do this for several rasters and it is only one step in a chain, I would like to include it as a step in the graphical modeller of QGIS.This provides the GDAL Raster Calculator, the modeler only tool Calculator and the Saga Raster Calculator, but in none of these I can find out, what to type in to get the desired result.

Comment: Could be that you need quotes around the band definition and the whole input. Like ""Slope@1>=50"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose "GDAL Raster calculator", `Input layer A` would be `Slope` (though grayed out in modeller), `Number of raster band`= `1`, and the `Calculation in gdalnumeric syntax using...` would be `A*(A>=50)`.

Of `A*(A>=50)` the latter part (A>=50) returns 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE). So the resultant equation A times 1 or 0 (A*1, A*0) is equivalent to setting a threshold value.

Comment: Actually this seems like what I am looking for. However when I execute it like you proposed, I get the raster layer in the middle as a result (first image is the raster with the slope values), instead of the expected lower raster image.

Comment: @Moo I am not sure but it seems you are trying to achieve a binary (1, 0) image. Then the equation would be (A>=50) or (A<50) depending on to which color each 1 and 0 is assigned.

Comment: That is the solution I searched for: I simply did not add the braces.

Comment: @Moo I am glad it worked out. Sorry the braces  (I tried to highlight them) were misleading.